# Separate activation of <span> inside <li> of JQuery Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menuitem

I was wondering If I can have a separate element(`<span>`) on a `<li>` using JQuery Menu, as the default style is always activating the entire `<li>`
and what I need to have is to only activate the `<span>` being hover/focus by the user. Is this possible or can anyone guide me on where should start?

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B
    <ul>
      <li><span>B - 1.1</span><span>B - 1.2</span></li>
      <li><span>B - 2.1</span><span>B - 2.2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9a8k3bxa/1/) activates `B - 1.1` and `B - 1.2`  simultaneously.

Comment: Er... Remove the CSS for the second level hover of LI? Will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this kinda work for you:

```css
.ui-menu .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus > span {background: #fff;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus > span:hover {background: transparent;}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7z9dpdd/**

Tried another version to completely get the padding:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus > span {background: #fff; display: inline-block; margin: -5px 0; padding: 5px 0;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus > span:hover {background: transparent;}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fjmfk7qb/**

**Final Masterpiece**

```
.ui-menu { width: 150px; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu {width: auto;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item {padding: 0; width: auto; white-space: nowrap;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item > span {background: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 0;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus > span:hover {background: transparent;}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6p8trnnn/**

Comment: Hi Sir,thank you for your demo, but the last fiddle retain gray color on the side of the span not being activated @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Ok sir,thanks for the help,although span now are like dancing. :P thanks

Comment: @bumbumpaw What does it mean by dancing. Please don't use `sir`.

Comment: When you hover on the items,some borders use to show and hide.

Comment: @bumbumpaw That happens only when you hover on 2nd or above right?

Comment: @bumbumpaw I too noticed that. `:(`

Comment: Oops, borders are ok, I can handle it but the text moves. try to hover on B1.1 then B2.1

Comment: @bumbumpaw Using Chrome latest version: Check https://jsfiddle.net/6p8trnnn/, the texts won't move.

Comment: my chrome version is 47.0.2526.106 m,text do move like 1px from right to left or vice versa

Comment: @bumbumpaw The same link?

Comment: Yes, try to reproduce it by NOT clicking(just hover) the first level B then hover B1.1 and other sublist. :)

Comment: I didn't click on them. `:)`

Comment: @bumbumpaw If you don't mind, it is 3 am here, and I have office at 6 am. Need to get my sleep at least for 3 hours. `:(` Good night. Will wake up and discuss.

Comment: It happens on first load of fiddle or on first hover.

Comment: @bumbumpaw Checked on first load, ctrl + shift + r, incognito, no!

Comment: Ok thanks , I try to fix this one.Thanks for the help. :)